# Multiple User Connect to a Server with different Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, session

I am new to developing a website. I have question about user connection to server and database. For example, a server '**server1**' have 2 database and website, '**webdata1**' and '**webdata2**'. (I am not using any framework for both website development because i still not familiar in framework.)

*User A* log in and create session  to '**webdata1**' and *user B* log in and create session to '**webdata2**'. The problem is, when *user A* connect and create session to '**webdata1**', for '**webdata2**' also was connected with *user A* session instead of *user B*.

How can i split the user session and connection? It is by using framework (MVC Framework) solve this? Or is there another method for this?

```
 session_start();  
 include "connectdatabase.php";
 try  
 {  
      $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);  
      $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
      if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
      {  
           if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
           {  
                $message = '<label>All fields are required</label>';  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";  
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'username'     =>     $_POST["username"],  
                          'password'     =>     $_POST["password"]  
                     )  
                );  
                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                     $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];  
                     header("location:index.php");  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     $message = '<label>Wrong Data</label>';  
                }  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 catch(PDOException $error)  
 {  
      $message = $error->getMessage();  
 }
```

I use this code in login.php for both website. "connectdatabase.php" contain code to connect to server and database.

Comment: Can you please provide the framework you are using?
and as per your question, you can achieve that by putting different session cookie name for your websites or by different session path

Comment: I am sorry, i 'm not using any framework. @KevinPatel

Comment: Can you please provide the framework you are using? and as per your question, you can achieve that by putting different session cookie name for your websites or by different session path

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: I still learning and understanding Codeigniter framework, but i did not apply it on both website development. @KevinPatel

Comment: I provide code regarding session. @RifkyLTF

Comment: On another note: Looking at your code suggests that you are storing the user's password in an unhahshed format in which ever database. Do not do that, instead use `password_hash` when storing and `password_verify` when validating a user at logon etc

Comment: ok so user A login to first website with its own credentials and user B login to second website with their own credentials too. when user B login with its own credentials, somehow user B login to second website as user A. am I right ?

Comment: Yes, yes @RifkyLTF. Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: You might, if the problem is understood correctly, find this of interest? https://websec.io/2012/08/24/Shared-Hosting-PHP-Session-Security.html

Comment: have you tried using different browser or different device maybe ?

Comment: So far, i'm using same browser and same device to access both website. @RifkyLTF

Comment: Sure @RamRaider, i will read and understand it.